# How to disable Can't Update Chrome warning on top right of Chrome menu in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-update

As shown in this screenshot

[image: Google Update Warning]

I have tried rename chrome update file, disable Google Update Service, add registry as suggested in this website
https://digicruncher.com/turn-off-chrome-auto-update/
but this warning still appears every time I open chrome.

My chrome version is 88.0.4324.190